# FFT has unexpected DC component

Tags: fourier-series, matlab

I have a mixture of Gaussians and I want to look at their power power spectrum. The spatial distribution looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/kFRKZ.jpg?1]

It's already been convolved with a Gaussian window function. I subtract the mean over all values and run an FFT in matlab.
For the power spectrum I used $|\mathcal{F}|^2 $ and the image under is a section through the middle of the 2D phase space.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/TuimV.jpg?1]

The zero phase component is orders of magnitude bigger than the rest of the spectra; given the nature of the problem I expected the power spectral density to look like a combination of Gaussians.

Edit:
The data is initially given as a bivariate poisson process, defined on $ \mathbb{R}^2$. The weights are assumed to be equal and the Gaussians are equally spaced on a hexagonal grid. Now, I'm supposed to estimate the variance of the Gaussians, and wanted to do it using the empirical characteristic function,because the modified EM doesn't work well with data (I guess it's because sample is relatively small ~300 points in total). Following supervisor's suggestion, I estimated a density using Gaussian kernels, and then ran the FFT.
Concerning the Matlab implementation:
The 2D spatial density matrix is 'x'

```
nfft= 2^(nextpow2(max(size(x))));
fftx = fft2(x,nfft,nfft);
mx = abs(fftx)/length(x);
mx = mx.^2;
```

I selcted arbitrarily a section and plotted plot(ffshift(mx(2048,:)))

Edit2: I added a link to the data.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5sgz0ataxe9z3s/FFT_problem_DataSet.mat

Comment: I'm confused by your units in your plot. What is the meaning of -100 cycles per meter? Power spectrum distributions typically have a point at infinity at the origin. Perhaps this is responsible for the result you're seeing? Have you tried looking at your result when eliminating this point? Also, power should be a log axis.

Comment: I suggest that this be moved to dsp.SE

Comment: @EdGorcenski, I should edit the units, I made the graph in a hurry. (I prefer to show the symmetrical interval $-\pi/2 - \pi/2$, because  eventually I want to estimate the distribution.) I'll cut the value at zero, and have a look.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, should I move/re-post it to dsp.SE?

Comment: Ask the moderators to migrate the question to dsp.SE. I am not absolutely sure how to get their attention except by clicking on the "flag" link and putting in the request in the window that pops up.

Comment: @Peter You might have some better luck at DSP, but you may want to add more info. As I understand it, you're looking at an $R$-spectrum of a periodogram of a spatial process. The periodogram is going to have a point at the origin going to infinity. Remove it, and you should be OK. Adding some code or some additional commentary regarding your method will help clear things up.

Comment: @peter If I can understand your question I will be answering it. So you have a signal that is $1D$ signal right? which is a random signal and the distribution of this signal is a gaussian mixture model. From the signal you have, you want to estimate the parameters of the mixture. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören The problem is a $2D$ Gaussian mixture model, but I would appreciate help with with the $1D$ - it's a start.

Comment: @Peter I dont think that 2D will make an extra problem. What parameters do you want to find from the gaussian mixture model? $\epsilon$, $\sigma$, $\mu$? what about the correlation coefficient? Is it known?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören. I want to estimate the three parameters, $\epsilon, \sigma, \mu$. The correlation is assumed zero.

Comment: @Peter Are you sure that you're subtracting the mean before doing the FFT?

Comment: @JimClay, yeah. Did it inline and did it in two steps, both gave an identical looking result. Someone suggested that I'm dealing with a $2D$ Dirac comb convoluted with a Gaussian and as a consequence I should expect a delta function at phase zero. I don't understand why the plot looks this way- the zero phase component's way too big.

Comment: Could you post your data file somewhere?

Comment: @pichenettes, I added the data in the question. It's slightly different from the original post, because I noticed the convolution in the top figure isn't smooth.

Comment: @Peter what sort of data is that? I guess it is the 2D plot of the densities right? If your signal is zero mean random signal you will not see a peak at zero. It never happens. plot(abs(fft(randn(1,100)))) for example.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören, you're right- it's a 2D plot of the densities. The densities are recorded in a matrix C and I run the fft as fft2(C-mean(mean(C)),nfft,nfft). I checked mean(mean(C-mean(mean(C)))) and got ans = 5.4906e-019.

Comment: @Peter what do you wanna do with the fft of densities? If you wanna have the PSD of your signal then you need to take the fourier transform of your signal’s autocorrelation function.

Comment: Would it be possible to post your entire MATLAB script? There seems to be some confusion as to what the data represents and exactly what you've done. As others noted, if you truly subtract the mean of a signal before calculating its DFT, you should not see a peak at zero frequency.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören, the acf can be calculated using the FFT using the Wiener-Khinchin theorem. Then the acf is then the IFFT of $|\mathcal{F}|^2$, and the PSD should be just $|\mathcal{F}|^2$, right?

Comment: @Peter you You can estimate the PSD as $|{\cal{F}}|^2$. First this is an estimation. Second you do it over random samples. The idea of getting the autocorrelation function from the PSD is not valid. as Jason R mentioned.

Comment: @JasonR, I didn't know that. I'll use xcorr2 to calculate the autocorrelation function.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören, I wanted to calculate the PSD to check if I'm on the right track. The main problem is still estimating the parameters of the Gaussians.

Comment: @Peter: Actually, I retract my previous statement; I had a mental failure. I'm deleting the comment to prevent confusion.

Comment: @Peter PSD of a random independent noise process is flat. So it doestn give some idea. So you have a signal $s\in\mathbb{R}^2$ which is produced by a mixture model. Please let me ask some more questions to understand more. Do you assume that you know the total number of gaussian densities? how many are there in total?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören, the Gaussians are periodic on all of $\mathscr{R}^2$ and their number is unknown because it depends on the sample.

Comment: @Peter there is a problem in this definition. Do you have a signal which has a Gaussian shape or do you have Gaussian mixture model where you obtain your random samples. If you have a Gaussian mixture model, then the number of densities in your model cannot be dependent on the signal. They are just fixed. However it might be the case that you are asked to estimate first the number of densities then the parameters. Else makes no sense.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören. I'm sorry, I'm not too familiar with the terminology but I think most accurately, I have a periodic signal with a Gaussian shape. The period of this signal is somewhat complicated, because the Gaussians appear on vertices of hexagonal tiling. Each Gaussian is assumed to represent the same signal, so it has the same covariance and same amplitude.

Comment: @Peter now it is abit more clear. You have a periodic signal and this signal is stochastically modeled is that true? where does this signal come from? Is it finite or infinite?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören, yes the signal is modeled stochastically. 
The signal comes from neuronal measurements and the density in the plot represents the frequency with which the neuron emits an electrical spike. It's assumed that the signal is infinitely periodic.

Comment: @Peter Ok so in this case evaluation of PSD can make sense. As long as I understood this data is an experimental data and depending on some random factors. the power of the Gaussians are changing based on the random facts. Where is this randomness coming from? and from this signal what do we want to learn?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören. The experimental data depends on the x,y spatial coordinates and some noise. There are essentially two sources of randomness, the neuronal activity is stochastic and the signal is not intially measured at each point of the x,y plane. The densities in the graph are reconstructed from point processes; that is, the measurement originally  registers pairs x,y coordinates for each neuronal event. Then,the ensemble of events is transformed to a density. The obtained density represents the event distribution and I want to estimate the $\mu,\Sigma$, and possibly weight and spacing.

Comment: @Peter So we have a $2D$ data on the spatial axes $x$ and $y$ coming from neural activity. The data is in nature stochastic and as long as I understood there is a measurement error. I think it is a kind of phase shift with a certain parameter. However you finally came up with a $2D$ density taking into account the signal model. Now you have the density (as you gave in the first figure) and you would like to find parameters $\boldsymbol\mu,\Sigma$. Is this a stationary process? please correct me if I misunderstood any points.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören, you got it exactly right. Basin off of the property that the cdf $F_x (x_1...x_n)=F_x(x_{1+t}...x_{n+t})$, the process is stationary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and the obvious algorithm for the solution of this problem is the **EM** algorithm. This algoritm is getting worse in the number of parameters. It is also too much dependent on the initial conditions.

The drawbacks of this algorithm can be circumvented by parallel computing. This means you have $N$ **EM** algorithms run simultaneously which have different initialization points. The final algoritm takes all parameters estimated by **N** processors and based on the wellness of the fit gives the final decicion.

Another method is to use the central moments until **Mth** order. When written in a parametric form each **xth** order moment gives a linear/non-linear combination of parameters which are to be estimated. From here one can construct a test. Of course the moments should also be estimated from the data.

Another method would be to employ a better search algorithn. That is called particle swarm optimization. It will run similar to **EM**. However it is a stochastic algorithm have different characteristics than **EM** such as to be able to deal with more number of parameters. It is a kind of team optimization algorithm.

Thats all in my mind at the moment. Good luck with the experiments.

Comment: I've been looking into the EM and the method of the moments, the first looks a bit more appealing because I'm a bit pressed for time. Is it possible to run the EM on non-categorical data? The Matlab implementation of EM allows only for binary data; if it were possible to use the EM on the densities, as plotted in the top figure, I should be fine.

Comment: Yes sure. Implementation is also quite easy. Fix the parameters with respect to all densities except for one. And estimate the parameters of the unknown density using the regular way. Since all other densities are assumed to be known in this stage, maximum likelihood estimation should maximize the likelihood of $f_1(\mu_1,\sigma_1,\epsilon_1)+f$. As $f$ is constant, maximum likelihood estimation of $\mu,\sigma,\epsilon$ is simple. In the next iteration, use the parameters that you found in the first stage and now you have $f_2(\mu_2,\sigma_2,\epsilon_2)+f$ for the maximul likelihood estimation